# Not receiving emails in AWS SES when routing emails to it via Google Apps

Tags: email, email-server, g-suite, amazon-ses

I have a domain that uses google apps for emails. We have specific email addresses for automated emails, say, no-reply@example.com. We are trying to do automated replies saying, "sorry, we don't support replies".

The problem right now is that emails go straight to our google inbox, so I am trying it with a new email address, say no-reply2@example.com. The problem now is that SES is not receiving anything, but I am not getting any failures when sending an email to no-reply2@example.com. What's wrong?

Here's the setup on Google Apps:

[image]
[image]

Here's the setup on AWS SES:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can't point your MX records at both SES and google apps. You will need to setup the account on google apps to forward all emails to SES. Also, im sure you can setup auto-reply in gapps.

Comment: I didn't try to do that. I am trying to use google routing rules to route emails for 1 email address to AWS SES.